# Does CloudFlare make a site a greater potential DDOS target?

Tags: ddos, cloudflare

CloudFlare has gotten a lot of press recently as protecting businesses from DDOS attacks. But from looking at their twitter feed, it looks like they are targeted every day, and large segments of their customers are affected.

My question is: If I were to sign up with them to protect my sites from the possibility of a massive DDOS attack specifically at my sites, do I now make my sites dependent upon a high profile target for DDOS attacks?

Whereas I am otherwise a relatively low-profile target on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

"and large segments of their customers are affected."

An issue being reported about a data center or attack does not mean the issue is impacting all customers at all. We post to our feed whenever we know something might impact some customers as a matter of transparency.

If you're talking about individual reasons that an individual site may be attacked, they are:

1. Extortion (pay me or I'll attack your site).
2. Political/Social (I don't like what you say or the content on your site).
3. Competitive (competitors knock you offline to impact your sales).

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. What I mean is that from reading your customers' tweets and other media sources, they complain about frequent latency and reliability issues using CloudFlare. So to use a metaphor, does that mean a site pays a smaller tax to avoid the massive DDOS attack? If I'm not a target now (yet), will I see some user-perceived performance degradation (even ocasionally) by using CloudFlare?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily you will be targeted for ddos attack. Most of the sites targeted usually has some traffic or lets say, incredible amount of visitors / audience.

While cloudflare is protecting you from ddos, they most likely absorb the unwanted bandwidth before it reaches your server, compare to unprotected sites, they absorb 100% of the unnecessary bandwidth, sooner or later once your website hits bandwidth cap, web host are going to charge you if you want to add extra bandwidth.

I have subscribed cloudflare's services and so far my website are still ddos free.

Answer (score 0):

Your website wouldn't be affected by other attacks targeting Cloudflare, unless it's a really, (I mean really!) huge attack. Cloudflare is damn good at load balancing.

If I were you, I'd be more concerned about false positives and attack bandwidth caps (when on a free plan). CF is a good starter solution, but If you are looking for some serious and more importantly cost-efficient protection, take a look at ddos protected hosting providers like [Prolexic](https://coinshost.com/) (USA) or [Coinshost](https://coinshost.com/) (Switzerland).